# Converting Int into Word 8 in Haskell

Tags: haskell

So I am working on a project to help me get more comfy with Haskell, and possibly do some cool stuff. I am pulling in binary .MP3 files, and turning them into word8 arrays, but am running into a problem pulling off the bitwise operations.

I have boiled down the necessary operation to simple constant functions like this below, using a function from the Data.Word module, but am having trouble pulling up the specific Word8 instance and function:

```
one :: Word8
one = fromInteger 1
```

I am using the function from [this](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Word.html#line-98), but I am not having a Word8 Typed returned.

Now since I am fairly new to Haskell, and come from the very different OOP world I may be completely missing the easy answer, or obvious reason for this, but I feel I am just missing a simple import or deceleration. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong, or at least point me in the right direction?

Edit:
Error I get:

```
Iom.hs:13:7:
No instance for (Num word8) arising from a use of `fromInteger'
Possible fix:
  add (Num word8) to the context of
    the type signature for one :: word8
In the expression: fromInteger 1
In an equation for `one': one = fromInteger 1
```

When I tried "Num Word8" as:

```
zero :: Num Word8
zero = fromInteger 0
```

I get the error:

```
Iom.hs:12:8:
Expected a type, but `Num Word8' has kind `GHC.Prim.Constraint'
In the type signature for `one': one :: Num Word8
```

Edit 2:

Looks like this was the result of using "word8" instead of "Word8" for the type.

Comment: Your mistake is in capitalization.  `Word8` not `word8`.  Lower case types are type _variables_ - as in, they are fully polymorphic.  Also, numeric literals don't need to be converted.

Comment: or maybe more to the point the `fromInteger` is called for you by GHC(i) when you are using a numeric literal in code

Comment: btw: please include the errors you get in your message - I'm not sure here if I understand your problem correctly (is it a type in your actual code - as Thomas pointed out - or just when you copied it here?)

Comment: Added Error message and more detail

Comment: It looks like the word8 vs. Word8 typo might have been the issue. testing.